# merge condition is not working in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two tables one is (providerLoc) and another one is (tmpProviderLoc) I need to take three columns combination from tmpProviderLoc and need to check the records exist in ProviderLoc

Case 1 : If record exist in providerLoc i need to update another column(Npi) in providerLoc based on column (npi) in tmpProviderLoc

case 2 : if not exist i need to insert the values in providerLoc

for that I have written below query:

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[ProviderLoc]  AS PL
    USING
    (
       select *
from   (
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by [Location_ID],[PProviderTaxID]
          ,[POBOXZIP] order by [Location_ID],[PProviderTaxID],[POBOXZIP]) as row_number
   from [dbo].[TmpProviderLoc]
       ) as rows
where row_number = 1
    ) AS TPL

        ON TPL.[Location_ID] = PL.[ecProviderID]
        AND TPL.[PProviderTaxID] = PL.[TaxID]
        AND TPL.[NPI] = PL.[NPI]
        AND TPL.[POBOXZIP] =  PL.[POBOXZIP]

        WHEN MATCHED THEN  
           UPDATE SET PL.[NPI] = CASE 
                                   WHEN TPL.[NPI] = NULL THEN PL.[NPI]
                                                        ELSE TPL.[NPI]  
                                END
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
        INSERT (EcProviderID,TaxID,NPI,POBOXZIP,ProviderLocationStatusID,CreatedON) 
        VALUES (TPL.[Location_ID],TPL.[PProviderTaxID],TPL.[NPI]
                ,TPL.[POBOXZIP],1,GETDATE());
```

But I am failing in updating the NPI value -- if npi value is new in tmpProviderLoc it is not updating in ProviderLoc..

Could any one please look into this issue..
or any other way to go through this kind of checking

Comment: It's kinda hard to answer without sample data. Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL+DML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equal symbol in this is incorrect: WHEN TPL.[NPI] = NULL THEN PL.[NPI]

Use **IS NULL**

```
WHEN TPL.[NPI] IS NULL THEN PL.[NPI]
```

NULLs are special. They are "indeterminate" so they cannot be equal or unequal to anything purely because they just cannot have any value "determined". NULLs are the absence of value and equal/unequal does not apply.

To discover if NULL exists use **IS NULL** - or - **IS NOT NULL** to discover if there is a non-null value.

Comment: Great. Store that IS NULL for recall later :)